# Setting beamer text font

Tags: beamer, fonts

I want to set the font of the text inside a frame, and also the ones inside a block to FranklinGothic. I downloaded the `.ttf` files for this font, and I put them on the local path, and also installed them at `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/franklingothic`. Then I use the following header in the tex file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.9em,wd=0.8\paperwidth]{frametitle}
            \insertframetitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    \definecolor{cool_blue}{RGB}{35,137,154}
    \definecolor{cooler_blue}{RGB}{0,72,81}
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \setbeamercolor{titlecolor}{fg=cool_blue}
    \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=titlecolor}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=cooler_blue}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family={\fontspec{calibri}}}
    \setbeamerfont{example text}{family={\fontspec{FranklinGothic}}}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Background}
sample text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Yet, I don't see the FranklinGothic font inside the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only the ITC FranklinGothic. Change it to your font name.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Calibri{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\Gothic{FranklinGothicLT-Medium}

\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\definecolor{cool_blue}{RGB}{35,137,154}
\definecolor{cooler_blue}{RGB}{0,72,81}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamercolor{titlecolor}{fg=cool_blue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=titlecolor}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=cooler_blue}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\Calibri}
\setbeamerfont{example text}{family=\Gothic}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.9em,wd=0.8\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Background}
    sample text

\begin{Example}
    foo
\end{Example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the used and included fonts are:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type             
------------------------------------ ----------------  
BCUJUB+Calibri-Bold                  CID TrueType     
BSEWJS+LMSans10-Regular-Identity-H   CID Type 0C      
BWQWZA+FranklinGothicLT-Heavy        CID TrueType
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How did you find out the exact name of font 'FranklinGothicLT-Medium' ? I mean, how should I check the name under which it is stored in my system?

Comment: There is a small program: `otfinfo -I <filename with path>` which shows you the internal names. However, you can use the file name instead. I prefer the symbolic names.

Comment: I still don't have the Gothic font. Also, I think your output too doesn't have the Gothic font, it is the default beamer font

Comment: In my example `Background` is in Calibri, `sample text` in the default latin modern sans and `foo` as part of  the Example environment in Franklin Gothic. That was what you wanted!

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted. But I believe the `foo` in your output is not Franklin Gothic, but it is the default font of beamer

Comment: no, it is Franklin Gothic. Delta it and the font is not embedded in the PDF.